# Node js REST Service mongodb distinct array empty

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, distinct

I'm a junior developer and I'm developing a REST Service using Node JS, Express, MongoDB on Azure.
On my DB i have a Collection of more machine with a model, type, etc fields and when I do a query distinct i receive as a response an array of string.
Example:

```
[
"Massey Ferguson",
"JOHN DEERE",
"FENDT",
"NEW HOLLAND",
"CASE-IH",
"DEUTZ-FAHR",
"VALTRA/VALMET",
"SAME",
"BCMH",
"CASE",
"CATERPILLAR",
"CHALLENGER"
]
```

Now i have write a GET service:

```
router.get('/machine_brand', function(req,res){
Machine.find().distinct('Brand', (err, items) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({ status: 'ko', data: {msg: err.message }});
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(items);
    res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: {msg: 'Brands available', brand:items}});
});
});
```

The service response is 200 but as json response i receive an array empty

```
{
"status": "ok",
"data": {
    "msg": "Brands available",
    "brand": []
}
```

}

Why the array is empty?
How can have into array the same reponse of mongo query that i have run on robomongo?
I have tried also with find() and the ruslt is the same: a empty array []

```
router.get('/machine', function(req,res){
Machine.find({}, (err, machine) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({ status: 'ko', data: {msg: err.message }});
    }
    res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: {msg: 'Lista machine', machine: machine}});
});
```

});
And this is my model:

```
var db = require('../config/db.js');


var MachineSchema = db.Schema({
Brand: {type: String, required: true},
Model: {type: Number, required: true},
Version:{type: String, required: true},
Hp: {type: String, required: true}

});

db.model('Machine', MachineSchema);

module.exports = db.model('Machine');
```

Thanks for your help
Best,

Comment: What does `console.log(items);` print?

Comment: Hi Sid, print "[ ]" array empty. I have tried with length and result is 0; but on robomongo the same query have array populated

Comment: Can you try `Machine.find({}).distinct('Brand', (err, items)` just to be sure, let me know

Comment: I have try but with same response

Comment: `Machine.distinct('Brand', (err, items)` if you can check this as well, trying to figuring it out ;)

Comment: I have tried also in this way but result is always the same

Comment: Looks really strange to me, can you make a test with `Machine.find({})` without the  `distinct` part and update the question with the output?

Comment: i have update my question

Comment: Can you show the model code?

Comment: I have updated my post with model code

Comment: Hi Sid, my DB is on Azure and the collection are imported from csv. I have noticed that if a collection was create before by a post service is ok, but the collection imported by csv no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it should work, and the fact that you're getting a response at all is a good sign.  My first suggestion would be to make sure that the collection name matches correctly with your DB.  I just tested a piece of code (fetching a collection with name 'UsErS') and it seems that MongoDB does NOT throw an error in this case, but simply creates a new empty collection with the name provided.

edit: if you're getting a populated response using a different library, then also double check the initialization of your library to make sure its hitting the correct db, etc.

Comment: in my case by default shell connects to admin db, that has caused this issue. There should be warning for non existing collection for such queries in MongoDB.